# Visual Studio Code hide all js files unless in vendor folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to put together the perfect workspace settings for my Typescript project. I have my .js and .js.map files all generated alongside my ts files but I don't want to display them in the file tree. I know I can use `"files.exclude"` in the workspace settings to define glob patterns to not show in the tree however I'm not sure how to do what I want exactly.

I want to hide `**/*.js` unless the js file has a parent folder called `vendor` because my typescript project has some non-ts libraries that I would like to see in my file tree.

How can I make this happen?

I've tried setting a rule like `"**/vendor/*.js"` to false but that seems to be just as good as not having that rule present in the file at all, it doesn't go out of it's way to include files matching that pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see our documentation for hiding derived resources: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_hiding-derived-javascript-files

Comment: I do appreciate the answer and it does work but answers that are only links to outside sources are less than ideal.

Comment: I cut and past straight from your link: `"**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts" }`. Everything in my vendor folder shows because they don't have matching ts files.