# VSCode: Exclude files with same name if they already exist at different location

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a source file at `path/source/file.h` and another file generated from that source file at `path/to/generated/file.h`.

I would like to exclude the latter file from the VS Code File Explorer and Search Results, whenever the former file already exists. (But I don't want to exclude the *entire* folder `path/to/generated` because it may contain some non-generated files.)

The documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling) talks about using the `when` clause to do this. There, the generated files have the same basename but different extensions from the source files, and so the match pattern for the `when` clause is simple.

However, I'm not sure what the glob pattern should be when **both** basename and extension are the same, but parent folders are different. (nor do I know if this is even supported by VS Code).

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work, I can still see the generated files:

```
"path/to/generated/**/*.h": {"when": "path/source/**/$(basename).h"}
```

---

I suspect it doesn't work because `$basename` isn't simply the name of the file, but rather *everything* including the parent path, before the extension?

So, anyone have ideas on what the correct pattern should be, if one exists? Is there some keyword other than `$(basename)` to match *only* the filename and nothing else?

Comment: Somewhat similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018128/visual-studio-code-hide-all-js-files-unless-in-vendor-folder